# How to partition a graph into several parts and color them separately in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am really really new to Illustrator. I want to draw two bell-curves as in the pic attached. I want to partition the two bell-shapes into 4 regions and color them separately. I figure that the first thing to be done is to separate the figure into 4 separate regions - the two separate blue pieces and two separate red (upper and lower parts of the red bell-shape defined by an unseen border of the blue shape) pieces. How?

[image]

Ok, I have made some improvement - using Live Paint. See attached second fig. How do I paint the small blue tail with a 4 th color?

[image]

Comment: Are you confident enough with the pen tool to merely draw the shapes? How far have you gotten?

Comment: @scott I drew the 2 curves using Curvature Tool. I assume some existing tool (or methods) can partition the 4 pieces. That is all I have gotten.

Comment: You probqbly dont want to use live paint. But shapebuilder.

Comment: @joojaa - you should make that an answer.

Comment: like Joojaa said, Shape-builder or pathfinder tools all the way. They will make the job easy.